# Site can't load System.IO after installing Application Insights server monitor

Tags: asp.net, azure-application-insights

I've just installed Application Insights Server Monitor on a test server, where I had a fully functional .net 4.0 ASP.net Site.

After enabling AI on the site, When I attempt to load it, I get an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO' or one of its dependencies.  
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly 
reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO' 
or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition 
does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x80131040)
```

When I enable AI, it copies a couple .net dlls to the sites /bin/,
System.IO.dll and System.Threading.Tasks.dll. If I delete them, the issue resolves itself, but AI does not receive any telemetry from the site.

What do I need to do to resolve this issue, and enable monitoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check the assembly version of System.IO.dll in bin folder and binding redirect defined in web.config after the instrumentation? 
If System.IO.dll is of 2.0.10 version and binding redirect says 2.0.9, then it's an issue that will be fixed during next update early next week. 
As a workaround you can manually set binding redirect to 2.0.10 for now. I'm very sorry for this bug!

Comment: Thanks! They are 2.0.9 .dlls now that I've installed .net 4.5.2 (had been 2.0.8 with .net 4.5). I'll give it another try next week.